# How to catch the runtime error DATREF_NOT_ASSIGNED?

Tags: exception, abap

Is it possible in ABAP to catch DATREF_NOT_ASSIGNED using TRY-CATCH clause?

DATREF_NOT_ASSIGNED is of category ABAP programming error, which means:
"Errors in the ABAP program, such as a division by zero or a catchable exception that was not caught."

Problem: modify below code to catch the DATREF_NOT_ASSIGNED:

```
data gv_i type ref to i.
gv_i->*17.
```

Simple handling of this error is:

```
data gv_i type ref to i.
if gv_i is initial.
  gv_i = new #( ).
endif.
gv_i->*17.
```

The desired solution will use TRY-CATCH or other construct for handling exceptions/errors. Below code does not work:

```
data gv_i type ref to i.
try.
  gv_i->* = 17.
catch CX_ROOT.
  gv_i = new #( ).
endtry.
```

Comment: Note that the handling using `if gv_i is initial` doesn't cover all the cases in case the bound data is freed (the reference would have no bound data, but the reference would also be NOT initial). The handling using `if gv_i is not bound` covers all the cases.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot catch DATREF_NOT_ASSIGNED.

The [ABAP language documentation for the Dereferencing Operator ->*](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_754_index_htm/7.54/en-us/abendereferencing_operator.htm) confirms this:

> If the data reference variable contains the null reference, the **non-handleable** exception DATREF_NOT_ASSIGNED is raised when the dereferencing operator is used.

Use `is not bound` to check for null references:

```
data gv_i type ref to i.
if gv_i is not bound.
  gv_i = new #( ).
endif.
gv_i->*17.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot handle such an exception as it is purely a programming error that simply needs to be fixed.

Even `CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS OTHERS = 8` will not help.

```
REPORT zzz.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA gv_i TYPE REF TO i.
  CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS OTHERS = 8.
    gv_i->* = 17.
  ENDCATCH.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    gv_i = NEW #( ).
  ENDIF.
```